# How to open a specific tab by ID on page refresh using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs, opencart

I am working in open cart. In my orders info page i have some custom tabs one of my tab is named as HX endicia labels.

```
<a href="#tab-label"><?php echo "HX Endicia Labels"; ?></a> // link to tab
<div id="tab-label" class="vtabs-content" style="display: none;"> // tab content, its by default display none when page loads.
```

On this tab i show some records from data base in table. on every row i have delete link as well which deletes current row from Database. When i click my delete link i call a delete_label method in controller and delete that row from DB its working fine till now. at the end of my function i reload my current order_info page.Page is refreshed when i delete a record. when page is refreshed my first tab is opened by default. what i want is to open my "#tab-label" tab when page is reloaded via this delete function. for this i coded like this.

```
public function Delete_label() 
{ 
/* my code to delete label */
$this->info();  // refreshing my page
echo " <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('tab-label').style.display = 'block';
</script>
";
}
```

Its not working.

Comment: the echo isn't executed because of your refresh

Comment: than what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect instad of refresh to a page that ends with the desired active tab

exp:
   html form for delete
   
    //other imputs

```
public function Delete_label() 
{ 
$tab = $_POST["showed"];//get the value from the hidden input
header('Location: '.$currentUrl.$tab);
}
```

in your refreshed page you do :

```
tab= window.location.hash.substr(1);//get the end of the url '#tab-label'
if(tab) {
   document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';//show the hidden tab 
}
```

Comment: there is no specific page , the active tab css is set to display block when its clicked and rest are set to display none

Comment: what if i refresh my #tab-label tab in the end of this function?

Comment: what do you mean by refresh ?

Comment: i mean updating my content only in my label content after delete click

Comment: what is your label content?

Comment: in your delete from you create a hidden input where you save the id of the tab you want to hide and than you redirect to the same url+hash, the js will take the id from the url and it will display the correct div